# PHP with ajax - Working with array

Tags: php, ajax

Im so confused. Been tyring to solve this myself for about two hours and going crazy!

I have a simple ajax call, getting an array, and adding that as options to a select.
This is working:

AJAX:

```
<script>
$("#press").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      if(result){
        $('#options').empty();      
        resultObj = eval (result);
        $.each(resultObj, function( index, value ){
            var option = $('<option></option>').attr("value", value).text(value);
            $("#options").append(option);
        });
      }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

and from the ajax.php:

```
$array = array("a","b","c","d");
echo json_encode( $array );
```

This is working and gives me:

```
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
```

What I cant figure out, is how to add a value to the dropdowns, so I get

```
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">b</option>
<option value="3">c</option>
```

I need help on how to change the array, and the ajax call correctly to include a value for each letter.
Say a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4

Any help would be SO GREAT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you format your array in PHP something like this...

```
$array = array(
    array("display" => "a", "value" => 1),
    array("display" => "b", "value" => 2),
    array("display" => "c", "value" => 3),
    array("display" => "d", "value" => 4)
);
echo json_encode( $array );
```

You can then have jQuery like this...

```
$.each(resultObj, function( index, row ){
    var option = $('<option></option>').attr("value", row.value).text(row.display);
    $("#options").append(option);
});
```

Comment: Worked great. Now I need to understand why! THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to change *option* values of *select* element to the numeric values.

JQuery's `each` function's callback already provides them through `index` argument.

On php-side format your `$array` var like

`$array = array(1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c", 4 => "d");`

And then use use indexes as values.

`var option = $('<option></option>').attr("value", index).text(value);`

Comment: the example array I used is only an example, once I get this working, the values will be from a db, so they will not be linier like 1,2,3,4 - I need the values for the letters to be dynamic, and part of the array I pass back.

Comment: In that case do on php-side something like `$array = array(1 => "a", 2 => "b",3 => "c", 4 => "d");
echo json_encode( $array );`.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.parseJSON function

```
   <?php
    $array = array("a" => 1,"b" => 2,"c" => 3,"d" => 4);
    echo json_encode( $array );
    ?>

if(result){
    resultObj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
    $.each(resultObj, function( index, value ){
        var option = $('<option></option>').attr("value", value).text(index);
    });
}
```